# Rails 4 - Using PUT instead of PATCH for updates

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I've recently upgraded to Rails 4 and discovered that updates are now PATCH instead of PUT.  The problem is that our current internal infrastructure doesn't support PATCH.  Is it possible to configure Rails to keep using old-style PUT instead or PATCH?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rails 4 supports both PATCH and PUT requests.

You can use optional method flag to specify the desired action. The default action is `:post`

`method: :put`  other actions(:post, :get, :delete, :patch)